# Anonymous inner class example validity concern

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I was trying to review some of the Java language using a spark chart I had once bought. Regarding the use of anonymous inner classes they give this example :

```
Dice rollDice() {
    return new Dice() {
        int number = (int)( Math.random() * 6 ) + 1;
    };
}
```

Problem is, I do not see how this would work, and can not get the compiler to accept it as a method within another class. The compiler complains about each reference to Dice "symbol can not be found."

Am I not understanding their example correctly or is this completely invalid code? Thanks in advance!

p.s. if this is working code, could someone provide me with an example of how it can be used?

Edit: I have found something that finally makes sense
The syntax for an anonymous inner class is shown below

```
new SuperClassName/InterfaceName() {
// Implement or override methods in superclass or interface
// Other methods if necessary
}
```

This above code is passed to a method that takes an instance of Superclass or completely implements the Interface. For instance, a method that has an `EventHandler`parameter and we have not already defined a class that implements the `handle(ActionEvent e)` method.

```
enlargeButton.setOnAction(
    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            circlePane.enlarge();
        }
    });
```

In this way, it will **truly be anonymous**. I think the example given in Java's own tutorial to be very poor.

Comment: Java doesn't have standard `Dice` class so that "symbol can not be found". That example probably contains some other parts which you are not showing us. Anyway this doesn't look like preferred way of using anonymous inner class which makes this example even unclear.

Comment: No, the example contains no other parts which I am not showing you. This is why I was asking the question, it was very unclear to me and I was wondering if I'm just not reading it properly or really do not understand this examples use. I'm now assuming their example is just garbage.

Comment: This code would compile if you would for instance place it in `class Dice{...}`. But still that example isn't very useful since we are just wrapping random number in Dice object. Such dice wouldn't let us return all 1-6 numbers, it can only return one number which makes this example at least unclear. If you want to learn about anonymous classes consider using official tutorials like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Their example in the java tutorial seems to completely disregard the idea of "anonymous". As I have been taught, and is previously defined in their own tutorial "anonymous" means it is not assigned to a variable and just used. Yet, they are assigning these objects to variables `frenchGreeting` and `englishGreeting`.  That has a declared name and therefore is not anonymous.

Comment: I would like to know what makes you think that "*"anonymous" means it is not assigned to a variable*" since that is not true. Anonymous class is a class without any *specific* name, so you can't reuse it somewhere else to reinstantiate it (at least not normally, you can do it with reflection but that is not the case). But we don't really care what is the name of that class, we just care how instance of that class behave. For instance we can create one ActionListener like `ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){ ... }` and pass it to many buttons.

Comment: Such `new ActionListener(){...}` construct will create instance of class which will implement `ActionListener` *interface* (it will be its subtype making it possible to hold it in `ActionListener al = ...`). Its `.class` file will be named something like `ActionListener$1.class` but you wouldn't be able to use that name like `new ActionListener$1();` in different place to create separate instances of that class (and ***that*** makes this class anonymous since we can't use that name anywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've mostly answered your own question and you will probably want to go through some full tutorial or documentation to understand things fully, but here are some answers to your immediate questions.

Your first sample code wont compile until you have a Dice class or interface you can extend.  So as an example you can get this code to compile:

```
class Dicey {
    interface Dice {
    }
    Dice rollDice() {
        return new Dice() {
            int number = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        };
    }
    public static void main(String... none) {
        Dice dice = new Dicey().rollDice();
        // dice.number; <-- not available
    }
}
```

Now you can do this, but as you suspect this is not a very useful things to do (for a few reasons) but the biggest problem is that after you create this anonymous instance there isn't really a way to get to the .number member.

More usually you would have an anonymous subclass implement some methods on the interface, so that you can actually do something with it.  So for example

```
class HelloAnonymous {
    interface Hello {
        String say();
    }

    Hello hello(String world) {
        return new Hello() {
            public String say() {
                return world;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... none) {
        System.out.println(new HelloAnonymous().hello("world").say());
        // prints 'world'
    }
}
```

gives you a way of making fantastically useful Hello objects that can say something.  Having said all this, writing anonymous inner classes is fairly old school because functional interfaces now largely replace the need for them.  So in this example you could have:

```
class HelloAnonymous {
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Hello {
        String say();
    }

    // old school
    Hello hello(String world) {
        return new Hello() {
            public String say() {
                return world;
            }
        };
    }

    // with lambda notation
    Hello alsoHello(String world) {
        return () -> {
            return world;
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... none) {
        System.out.println(new HelloAnonymous().hello("world").say());
        System.out.println(new HelloAnonymous().alsoHello("world").say());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since I don't know about 'Dice' class I cannot write same method but I try some thing similar to that. It compile and work can access 'number' variable by using reflection. My opinion is it is not very useful.  Following is my code:

```
  public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String a[]){
      TestClass aClass = rollDice();
      try {
        System.out.println("value of number : " + aClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("number").getInt(aClass));
      }
      catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

     static TestClass rollDice() {
      return new TestClass() {
        int number = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      };
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That example is extremely broken. Throw that source away. Try this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DieFactory {
  interface Die { int roll(); }

  static Die create(long seed) {
    Random random = new Random(seed);
    return new Die() {
      @Override
      public int roll() {
        return random.nextInt(6) + 1;
      }    
    };
  }

  // Now you can roll 2 dice pretty easily.
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    DieFactory.Die die1 = DieFactory.create(42);    
    DieFactory.Die die2 = DieFactory.create(24);    
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      System.out.println(die1.roll() + die2.roll());
    }
  }
}
```

Incidentally, the word "dice" is plural for the singular "die."